# Reading a .txt file that results in a stackoverflow error

Tags: java, recursion, split, java.util.scanner

Can someone please help me determine what I am doing wrong with my code. I am getting a stackoverflow error. At the end of my code I am using recursion and I don't have a base case to stop the program. It keeps looping and displaying my text file until I get a stackoverflow error.

```
public class Reader
   {
        public static String readFinalQuestionBank() throws Exception
        {   
            File textFile = new File("C:\\Users\\Joseph\\Documents\\School Files - NHCC\\CSci 2002\\FinalQuestionBank_JosephKraemer.txt");  //file location

            try
            {
                Scanner scan = new Scanner(textFile);                   //Scanner to import file

                while(scan.hasNextLine())                               //Iterator - while file has next line
                {
                    String qBank = scan.nextLine();                     //Iterator next line
                    String[] tempArray = qBank.split("::");             //split data via double colon

                    System.out.println(qBank);           //print data line
                }
                scan.close();                  //close scanner

            }
            catch(FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                 e.printStackTrace();
            }       
            return readFinalQuestionBank();         //use of Recursion
        }//end method readFinalQuestionBank
    }//end class Reader
```

Comment: What are you expecting the recursion to accomplish, other than to read the file again and again until you get a stack overflow?

Comment: You seem to have identified the problem already.  What else do you want to know?

Comment: Please specify what you are trying to accomplish with your code. As it stands, the code is the same as calling a non-recursive readFinalQuestionBank() in a while(true) block with the difference that your never-ending recursive call eventually eat up all the stack buffer for the running Thread and caused the exception.

Answer (score 0):

if your main objective is to read the whole input file by implementing recursivity take a look at the following example, it replaces the `while` statement with a recursive method call.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Reader
{
     public static String readFinalQuestionBank() throws Exception
     {   
         File textFile = new File("C:\\Users\\Diego\\Documents\\sandbox\\input.txt");
         String output = "";
         try
         {
             Scanner scan = new Scanner(textFile);                   
             output = readLineRecursively(scan);
             scan.close();                  
         }
         catch(FileNotFoundException e)
         {
              e.printStackTrace();
         }       
         return output;         
     }

    private static String readLineRecursively(Scanner scan){
        if(!scan.hasNextLine()){
            return "";
        }
        String qBank = scan.nextLine();                     
        return qBank + "\n" + readLineRecursively(scan);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        try {
            System.out.println(readFinalQuestionBank());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```